# Web Api - How to prevent users from accessing other users data

Tags: authorization, asp.net-web-api

I have been doing some research about authentication and authorization on web api.  I understand authentication (username/password) and ROLE based authorization, but what I'm confused about is authorization on data.

Say you have a user (user id 1) who is authenticated, an admin, and is associated to company ABC.  I have other users associated to ABC which user id 1 can update.  Now I want to update user id 2's name who is associated to ABC (which I should have access too).  I need to pass in something to identify user 2, ie put /user/2 plus post data.  I know on the server side that user 1 is allowed to update user 2 because he is authenticated and an admin.

Now I have user 100 who is associated to company XYZ.  User 100 should not be able to update user 2.  This is what I'm having a hard time finding information on.

What are some approaches/blogs/anything that can give some helpful ideas on how to prevent user 100 from accessing data outside it's company.

My thoughts are I could pass in the logged in users id (which I grab server side based on authentication) into the update stored procedure and do a check to make sure that user id is associated to the user being updated.  To me this seems tedious and ugly in that every stored procedure needs a user id parameter and a check to make sure they can access the data they are accessing (maybe this is correct).

I know how to authenticate and how to check role based authorization, the missing part is resource based authorization.

Thanks for the help.

Does anyone have any insight.  Its hard to believe that Role based Authorization is sufficient.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654218/how-to-prevent-users-to-access-other-users-data-with-dotnet-core-and-restful-ap

Comment: @kheit any luck on implementing this?

Comment: @kheit this is exactly my question. What is best practice to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

use the concept of authz where a user is prevented to see the details of other users

Comment: "use the Microsoft API" is kind of a solution, but lacks helpful details. Please provide some detail. Especially if you do NOT mean the MS thing, provide more explanation of what you are referring to and how it helps. Also, please take the [tour] and try for [answer].